# SkipToken length - HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am making a call to the GRAPH API using the delta method to get Users

```
/beta/users/delta?$skipToken=[SKIPTOKEN]
```

the length of my skip token returned on the last delta request using a delta token is 17005 characters, this in turn makes the URL too long.

What methods can we use to reduce the size of the skip token?
There are over 37000 users in our AAD what we are querying and this may be the problem but not sure how the skip and delta tokens are generated.

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Is there anyway to put the skip / delta tokens in a header value to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The skipToken generated from server-side due to server-side paging, try to use $top and odata:nextLink to do paging when querying large data.

[Check here for more details](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/paging.md)

Comment: Thanks Lee, I am using the delta method : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview the $top option is not supported as far as I am aware

Comment: you'll need to set the header if you want this to work: Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=YOUR_PAGE_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

This is something the team is aware of and we're investigating ways to fix it. In the meantime, you can workaround the issue by [wrapping your requests in a batch request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching#bypassing-url-length-limitations-with-batching), which moves the too-long URL into the body of the POST. Not ideal, but it gets around the issue while we work on making it better :)

Comment: Hi Jason, We have wrapped the requests now using the batch method, however, we are still having this same issue. This is the error returned by $batch `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD HTML 4.01\/\/EN\"\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/html4\/strict.dtd\">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request<\/TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text\/html; charset=us-ascii\"><\/HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Request Too Long<\/h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.<\/p>\r\n<\/BODY><\/HTML>\r\n`

Comment: Hi Jason, the bug seems to be still there. Could you give us an update on it ?